# apache 2.4 virtual hosts get list of domains from file

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

I have about 3000 plus domains and want them to point to the same folder.

Do I have to repeat this entry 3000 times
`<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerAlias www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>`

or does apache have some way to grab a list of domain names in a text file and generate the above entry?

I looked in the manual and may have missed the option if it exists.

apache 2.4 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Why do you want 3000 virtual hosts, instead of 1 virtual host with 3000 names?

Comment: I'd prefer that, but is that possible? So just point the dns for each of the domain names to the server's ip and have the above be the default entry?

Comment: If all the sites serve the same files, then why not? Just repeat `ServerAlias` as many times as you need.

Comment: ok that makes sense, do I even need the additional server alias entries if the A record for each domain points to the servers ip address?

Comment: Those are orthogonal. DNS only tells what your IP address is. Your web server still has to know what hostname to answer for.

Comment: So is there a way to include a text file with the 3000 domain names on the serveralias line? or does it look like ServerAlias domain1.com domain3.com domain3000.com

Comment: Sure, you can include a file, but you should probably just generate the configuration and save yourself a bunch of headaches.

Comment: I can generate it, but for ease of use for my friend it would be easier for them to just edit a text file with a domain per line.